# NSURLConnection with https

Tags: ios, https, nsurlconnection

I have to implement NSURLConnection with https if the certificate is trusted then connection should go normally if it is untrusted certificate then I have to get the confirmation from the user. How can I implement?

My Code..

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge 
{
    self.mHTTPLAuthenticationChallenge = challenge;
    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
    {


        NSString *theErrorMSG = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be \“%@\” which could put your confidential information at risk.",challenge.protectionSpace.host];

        UIAlertView *theAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:kAppName message:[ARCUtilities ARCLocalizedString:theErrorMSG] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:[ARCUtilities ARCLocalizedString:@"Continue"] otherButtonTitles:[ARCUtilities ARCLocalizedString:@"Cancel"], nil];
        [theErrorMSG release];

        [theAlertView show];
        [theAlertView release];
         [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

    }

}
```

Comment: You should avoid to ask a user whether she trusts the certificate or not. Besides it's difficult to display a nice looking representation of a certificate on iOS, a user would *always* tab or confirm *anything* which let her do what she intended to do. If something bad happens, a user would always blame *you* anyway, too.

Comment: How can I found which error is coming?

Comment: Actually that url is given by user only thats I need to give the warn d user. how can I do?